# Directory wildcard in Makefile pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to create a Makefile that will compile terminfo files residing in a directory via `tic`. `tic` also copies the termcap files it creates automatically to a system- or user-specific destination folder. For a regular user if the terminfo file is e.g. `screen-256color-bce-s.terminfo`, it will be compiled and copied to `~/.terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce-s`. So it will look something like this:

```
terminfo/screen-256color-bce-s.terminfo => /home/user/.terminfo/s/screen-256color-bce-s
terminfo/screen-256color-s.terminfo => /home/user/.terminfo/s/screen-256color-s
```

If I put something like this into my Makefile:

```
TISRC = $(wildcard terminfo/*.terminfo)
TIDST = $(foreach x, $(TISRC), $(HOME)/.terminfo/$(shell basename $x|cut -c 1)/$(shell basename $x .terminfo))

$(HOME)/.terminfo/s/%: terminfo/%.terminfo
    @echo "$< => $@"
    @tic $<

install: $(TIDST)
```

it works. However, I'd like to make it general, and use a wildcard in the target, i.e.:

```
$(HOME)/.terminfo/**/%: terminfo/%.terminfo
    @echo "$< => $@"
    @tic $<
```

to be able to add terminfo files to my local repository. The above, however, does not work. How can I specify a wildcard directory in a pattern rule?

Comment: I don't think you can; Make isn't very good with wildcards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with [GNU Make Secondary Expansion feature](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion):

```
all : ${HOME}/.terminfo/x/a
all : ${HOME}/.terminfo/y/b

.SECONDEXPANSION:
${HOME}/.terminfo/%: terminfo/$$(notdir $$*).terminfo
    @echo "$< ---> $@"
```

Output:

```
[~/tmp] $ make
terminfo/a.terminfo ---> /home/max/.terminfo/x/a
terminfo/b.terminfo ---> /home/max/.terminfo/y/b
```

As a side note, make provides [some path manipulation functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions), so that you don't really need to invoke the shell for that.

Comment: @Beta Well, sometimes one wishes that make had something like regex pattern matching, e.g. `/([[:word:]]+)/([[:word:]]+) : /build/\1/obj/\2.o`. But this would make it difficult to select a more specific rule. With `%` patterns the most specific pattern is the one where `%` matched the least number of characters, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use wildcards the way you're trying to, but if you don't mind using **eval** trickery, you can get the effect you're shooting for without having to spell out all the directory paths explicitly:

```
TISRC = $(wildcard terminfo/*.terminfo)
BASENAMES = $(notdir $(basename ${TISRC}))

MKDST = ${HOME}/.terminfo/$(shell echo $1 | cut -c 1)/$1
TIDST := $(foreach s,${BASENAMES},$(call MKDST,$s))
DIRLTRS = $(notdir $(patsubst %/,%,$(sort $(dir ${TIDST}))))

install: ${TIDST}

# $1 - Directory Name
# $2 - File name
define T
${HOME}/.terminfo/$1/$2 : terminfo/$2.terminfo
    @echo "$$< => $$@"
    tic $$<
endef

# This is the tricky part: use template T to make the rules you need.
$(foreach d,${DIRLTRS},$(foreach f,${BASENAMES},$(eval $(call T,$d,$f))))
```